# In what ways do some consider animal rights issues to be connected to feminist issues?

Tags: ethics, animal-rights

Some vegans consider animal rights issues to be an intersectional social justice issue, and connect speciesism to various other isms.

In what ways does this perspective consider animal rights issues to be connected to feminist issues?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The classic text on this is [*The Sexual Politics of Meat* by Carol J Adams](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/51714.The_Sexual_Politics_of_Meat)

It's a much contested text. Some of its key arguments linking feminism and animal rights are:

- Female animals are used to produce milk and eggs.
- Meat is presented as a macho, masculine food (and women in many places deprive themselves of food, including meat, to provide men with the meat men are believed to need).
- There is a parallel between the objectifying presentation of women as sexual objects and the objectification of animals as meat

You can read more on [Adams' website](http://caroljadams.com/). She is, of course, a vegan.